# React-Router skip search queries on back button press

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In the search page I'm using search queries. I want to skip changes in search queries and go back to the real previous page.

Now:

> /page1 -> /page2 -> /page2?id=1 -> /page2?id=1&order=max -(back)-> /page2?id=1 -(back)-> /page2? -(back)-> /page1

What I want:

> /page1 -> /page2 -> /page2?id=1 -> /page2?id=1&order=max -(back)-> /page1

Comment: you can try `https://www.npmjs.com/package/url` and create a URL with different `pathname` but with same query string

Comment: @DanielKrom I want to go back in history of react-router it be possible not going to another page. I just want to skip query changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pages you want to skip just use **replace** for navigation than **push** for them.

Let say your history stack is

/page1
Push another page
/page2
Push another page
/page3
Then there is only a query change on page3 and you want to go back to page2 on pop.

So just replace the /page3/ with /page3?q=test

So now the history stack will be

/page1

/page2

/page3?q=test

Answer (score 2):

On the query params changes, you can use **history.replace** instead of **history.push**.
So your URL changes in that scenario will not be pushed into the history stack.

```
this.props.history.replace(`${URL_TO_BE}${QUERY_STRING}`)
// this.props.history.push(`${URL_TO_BE}${QUERY_STRING}`)
```